# Error using lxml library  to parse xml in Python

Tags: python, xml, lxml, pretty-print

I am not able to use the pretty_print argument to print the xml. Any idea what could be wrong ?

I am attaching the code sample as well.

Thanks

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as etree
import os

def main():

    root = etree.Element("root")

    Series = etree.SubElement(root, "Element")

    SeriesID = etree.SubElement(Series, "Index")
    SeriesID.text = "80379"


    #print str(etree)
    #print(etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True))

    print(etree.tostring(root))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`xml.etree.ElementTree.tostring()`](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#functions) does not have a `pretty_print` parameter.

[`lxml.etree.tostring()`](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree-module.html#tostring) on the other hand has a `pretty_print` parameter.